# Should 7.5A "Air Con" circuit draw amps while vehicle is off?

Tags: nissan, battery-drain, fuse, frontier

I believe that my truck (1999 Nissan Frontier SE 3.6L) has a parasitic draw issue.

Was going through the fuse box checking voltage, the "Audio" 15A circuit had full voltage, which I believe is normal and okay as the circuit stays live to power the clock. But then the last fuse I check, 7.5A "Air Con" also had full voltage, so I switched over to DC Amps and it read 162mA being drawn.

[image: Picture showing multimeter on 200m DC amps setting showing 162.1 while hooked to positive battery post and negative fuse port where the 7.5A "Air Con" fuse goes.]

I'm assuming that this circuit should not draw any amps with the vehicle off. If that is the case and this is parasitic draw, I'm also not sure how to move forward to get this issue fixed.

Comment: From your snapshot, I think you're measuring current draw incorrectly (battery positive to  one side of the fuse terminal). Did you try placing a probe on each fuse terminal with the fuse removed? This measures current flow to the ac circuit, only. Measuring for parasitic current should be between a disconnected battery cable and battery terminal for an overall idea. Most vehicles may draw around 0.050 (50 milliamps) of current with ignition off to power memory (radio clock, radio presets, ecm, bcm and OnStar cellular). Current draw above 0.075 ma suggests a short or larger drain.

Comment: @FDryer I will re-measure tomorrow after work with the multimeter probes in the fuse ports and report back.